# Java chess covering board Queens and bishops

Tags: java, backtracking, chess

To get into the basics of Java I need to make a program which can determine the positions of several Queens and bishops on a m x n board. The amount of columns, rows, Queens and bishops is variable. The pieces have to be placed on such a way that all free places on the board can be attacked by at least one piece. The program must show one valid solution and the amount of possible solutions.

After some research I thought backtracking was the solution. I already implemented the functions to place the Queens. But first I was thinking that the bishops could be placed in the same way but after some tests it wasn't as effectieve as I hoped. The Queens are placed per column on a free spot and when you do this it will give a good solution with only Queens. But when all the Queens are placed and you continue with the bishops for each column, the solution os not the most effective solution.

Another idea to solve it is to calculate the most efficient position per queen/bishop. For every piece you've to calculate the number of places which it defences. This is also a good solution but when you do this I can't figure out how to calculate the total amount of solutions. And when you get a bigger board the execution time will grow exponently.

So I'm a bit stuck with the right way to solve this problem... Am I on the right track with one of those solutions? Or is there a better way to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I guess it's standard EightQueen backtracking algorithm with candidate rejection modified to test whether it covers at least one additional position.